# Android TimePicker - hour line is not align to center

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-dialogfragment, android-timepicker

I used Android TimePicker in my custom dialog.
The hours line is not align to center.
As you see the xml is look ok for center controller.
Is it possible at all to change the timepicker properties from custom dialog and not from FragmentDialog? How should i center it?

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleDateAndTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Today"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/changeDateAndTimeState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>

    </LinearLayout>

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/date_time_set"
    style="@style/Button.Buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_or_holo"
    android:text="@string/call_reminder_set_button"/>
```

[Custom dialog screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tffc3.png)

Comment: Where hours are not in the center? Double dots are in the center.

Comment: Yes, double dots are in the center. but i want that the full text: "9:02 AM" will be in the center. Do you have an idea?

Comment: answered on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option to center each of the element inside the `TimePicker` is not supported.
My last resort was to make custom view for the time picker with my layout.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html:
If you look here you will not find such methods or parameters.

Futher more, If you find a bug to setup this value, I do not, based on my experiance, really recommend to use something exapt default behavour. Because of there are a lot of different implementations for TimePicker.
Use the default behaviour or do nothing.

I only solutions: is to write your own timepicker using numberpicker, etc.